# ¿Cómo enviar una fecha de un datepicker de una pagina a un fullcalendar que está en otra ventana con angular 8/9?

Tags: aplicación-web, datepicker, fullcalendar, angular9

estoy haciendo una agenda de citas. La cosa es que mi sitio web tiene dos paginas, en una página (paciente) está el datepicker y en otra (calendario) está el fullcalendar. Lo que quiero es que cuando escoja una fecha (y hora, si es posible) de mi datepicker que está en la primera pagina, sea enviada al full calendar de la segunda página.

[image: en el rectangulo verde está el datapicker y el circulo verde es donde yo quiero se vea]

Espero haberme dado a entender.

Answer (score 0):

Si alguien mas vino aqui buscando lo mismo, encontre lo que buscaba en esta playlist.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ExQK8NVXEhE&list=PLaxZkGlLWHGVf7shYtr67aYN94suk9n4_

Advertencias: Los videos son un poco extensos. Lo digo si es que tienes prisa.